# Sphinx .net implementation

Tags: .net, sphinx

Is it possible to implementation  Sphinx (full-text search) in .net - MSSQL Application.

if so , any help how to implement the same, a small description will help a lot.

Comment: http://dotsphinxclient.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/sphinx-dotnet-client/

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sphinx.Client/

Answer (score 1):

We're using SphinxConnector.NET: http://www.sphinxconnector.net/

Comment: Not open-source. Costs a fortune.