# Sphinx over .net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, sphinx

Good time of a day!

I have:

1. Windows 2008 web server edition with big mvc project
2. Another dedicated MySQL server (Ubuntu Linux) with Sphinx engine installed on it

The task is to build the fast search over the photos database. I have spent to much time to find the working solution of mvc & sphinx with step-by-step instruction, cause im a new in this technoligie.

I want know how to use sphinx with .net mvc

I found 2 client libraries but both are with out any documentations (following this: [Sphinx .net implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400121/sphinx-net-implementation)) :(

Anybody can help? Thanks a lot!

PS> sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in any sphinx powered app, you have two main tasks:

1. Define/create your sphinx indexes (*sphinx.conf*)
2. Use a (.net) connector to submit your queries

For number **1** check the Sphinx docs, search for **mysql** and **sql_query**.

As for **2**, you should have something like:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Search() {
    string looking_for = Request.Form["search_item"];
    SphinxClient sphinx_client = new SphinxClient();
    List<Result> results = sphinx_client.Query(looking_for, "my_sphinx_index_name");
    // your view should know what to do with a Result collection
    return View(results);
  }
}
```

ps: I'm using this .net connector (which I wrote =P) http://dotsphinxclient.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Very easy to understand code in your Sphinx Connector. I checked other  implementations for C# sphinx-dotnet-client and some other on codeplex that could be found in Google, yours looks very interesting.

Comment: how do you connect to the index with that client?

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to use [Mysql .Net connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and communicate with Sphinx via SphinxQL interface.

This way gives you more functionality and you won't need to catch up changes from custom API development.

Comment: do you know is it possible to use linq to entities with SphinxQL?

Comment: I think its possible but not from the box. I'd try different implementation of linq database provider as Sphinx supports a subset of SQL that was dubbed as SphinxQL.